# how can i solve javascript variable error ? (let)

Tags: javascript

```
function solution(string, searchValue) {
   let answer;

      for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      
      var count_no_string = 0;
      
      //case 1
      if (searchValue[0] == string[i]) {
         let save = i; 
         let count = 0;
         for (let j = 0; j < searchValue.length; j++) { 
            if (searchValue[j] == string[save + j]) {
               count = count + 1;
               if (searchValue.length == count) {
                  answer = save;
                  return answer;
               } else{
                  console.log('f'+ count +' '+ searchValue.length);  
               }
            } else {
               console.log('일치하는 문서가 없습니다'  );
               return -1;
            }
         }
      }
      //case2
      else if(searchValue[0] != string[i]){
         count_no_string = count_no_string+1;
         console.log('test ' + count_no_string);
         
         if(count_no_string == string.length){
            //retrun -1;
            return -1;
         }
         
      }
   }
}
```

i don't know why count_no_string variable is always '1'
why?..

i found let, var, const js variable concept, but i can't solve it

thanks you so much

.........
.........
.......
.........

Comment: Where is this function getting called from? Can you post the a sample input and expected output?

Comment: if i call function    solution('hello aa world', 'aa');

Comment: input : hello aa world is string, aa is searchvalue, and output : we can see result in console, console says count_no_sring : test 1

Comment: you are resetting count_no_string to zero on each step of loop

Comment: You need to move `count_no_string` out of for loop

Comment: you are genius and angel